# How to empty data in rows except for certain row SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I empty all rows except specific ones that I want to keep in one SQL command.

I do NOT want to delete the rows. I only wan to empty all data in them.

The rows I want to keep are the ones with the following ID

```
23
2611
1817
322
2359
156
167
1664
901
576
```

All the other rows I want to empty in one SQL command.

My row ID go from 1-3000

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"?  Set all the columns to `NULL`?

Comment: No just blank empty boxes.

Comment: _blank empty boxes_ do not exist in MySQL.  Can you provide the schema or some context about your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the columns to `NULL` then something like this:

```
update t
    set col1 = null,
        col2 = null,
        . . .
    where id not in (23, 2611, 1817, 322, 2359, 156, 167, 1664, 901, 576);
```

You have to list each column individually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this :

```
UPDATE yourTable 
SET col1=null, col2=null ...
WHERE ID NOT IN (23 2611 1817 322 2359 156 167 1664 901 576)
```

But it will probably not work if you have `NOT NULL` constraints or `FOREIGN KEY`constraints.